# Getting children node only of specified node in openxml

Tags: sql, xml, nodes

I am Importing XML document into SQL tables. It is nested xml. I need to do 3 tables of it. I decided to use cursors. I am looking up, row by row through main node with first cursor. It works perfectly adding into first table. After adding it to table i want to access only that certain nodes children in FROM OPENXML statement using another cursor. So far i managed to read every children node data, not only one i am interested with. Can u tell me how to get into children nodes only of that cerain parent node i am reading with my first cursor?

```
<root>
  <mainnode> 
    <name>Main node 1</name>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name1</childrenname>
    </children>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name2</childrenname>
    </children>
  </mainnode>
  <mainnode> 
    <name>Main node 2</name>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name3</childrenname>
    </children>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name4</childrenname>
    </children>
  </mainnode>
</root>
```

Let's say it's my XML structure with data. I added it by bulk function. What i do now is

```
DECLARE @name varchar(400),
DECLARE kursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT name from OPENXML(@DocID, 'root/mainnode', 2)
WITH name

open kursor

FETCH NEXT FROM kursor into @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

--here i am adding record to first table, one by one with some insert
--and also here i need to reach children elements, but only of that certain mainnode 
 -- thats also the place to add second kursor
DECLARE childrenname varchar(400),
 DECLARE kursorchildren CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT childrenname from OPENXML(@DocID, 'root/mainnode/children', 2)
    WITH childrenname
OPEN kursorchildren
FETCH NEXT FROM kursorchildren into @childrenname
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--here i want to insert into table again, but only that childrens that are from actual row, not every form document.
FETCH NEXT FROM kursorchildren into @childrenname

   END

      CLOSE kursorchildren
      DEALLOCATE kursorchildren



    FETCH NEXT FROM kursor into @name

        END

  CLOSE kursorClaimsMain
  DEALLOCATE kursorClaimsMain
```

Comment: Please add some data and table structure to your question, may be sample code too, if you add sqlfiddle.com demo it would be even better :)

Comment: i added portions of code for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select it into plain table like this:

```
    declare @xml xml = N'<root>
  <mainnode> 
    <name>Main node 1</name>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name1</childrenname>
    </children>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name2</childrenname>
    </children>
  </mainnode>
  <mainnode> 
    <name>Main node 2</name>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name3</childrenname>
    </children>
    <children>
      <childrenname>Children name4</childrenname>
    </children>
  </mainnode>
</root>'

select 
     t.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as children_name
    ,t.value('(../name)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as node_name
    ,t.value('for $a in .. return 1+count($a/../*[. << $a])', 'int') as code_id
from @xml.nodes('root/mainnode/children') t(t)
```

You'll get identity for every main code and list of children. So, you can extract to any table you want.